# Complexity of searching common number in 3 arrays

Tags: performance, algorithm

There are three arrays a1, a2, a3 of size n. Function searches for common number in these arrays.
Algorithm is the next:

```
foreach n in a1
    if n is found in a2
        if n is found in a3
            return true

return false
```

My guess that worse case will be the next: a1 and a2 are equal, a3 does not contain any common number with a1.

Complexity to iterate through array a1 will be O(i).
Complexity to search array a2 or a3 is f(n) (we do not know how they are searched). 
My guess that overall complexity for worse case  would be:

O(n) = n * f(n) * f(n) = n * (f(n))^2

I was told that that it is wrong. 
What is correct answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n * f(n) * f(n) = n * (f(n))^2
```

> I was told that that it is wrong. What is correct answer then?

The correct answer for the given algorithm:

```
n * (f(n) + f(n)) = O(n*f(n))
```

You don't search `a3` array `f(n)` times for each `n` in `a1` so you should use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: what if it's found in a2 every time? then we will search it in a3, we should target the worst case

Comment: @Akram Mellice: if it's found in a2 every time: `(f(n) + f(n)) = 2*f(n) = O(f(n))` constant factors are not included in big-O notation.

Comment: the question itself highlights the one of the problem with relying solely on big-O in that it does exclude constant factors, for a small data sample `O(n^4)` can be faster than `O(n)` if it's really `K * O(n)` where `K` is a significantly large constant (`K>=n^3`), I believe that this is what they are really testing your knowledge of in this interview question.

Answer (score 1):

Place the elements of `a2` into a set `s2` and the elements of `a3` into a set `s3`. Both of these operations are linear in the number of elements of each array. Then, iterate over `a1` and check if the element is in `s2` and `s3`. The lookup is constant time. So the best achievable complexity of the whole algorithm is:

```
O(n1 + n2 + n3)
```

Where `n1` is the number of elements of `a1`, and so on for `n2` and `n3`. In other words, the algorithm is linear in the number of elements.

Comment: he didn't ask for a faster algorithms or a good one, he wants to know what is the complexity of the given algorithm, there are tons of different ways you can solve this problem

Comment: Well, sometimes what people _need_ is not what they _ask for_ :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO worst complexity is n.log n. You sort each one of arrays and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note here is what is the running time of the "is found" function ?

There are two possible answers :

case 1: If the a2 list and a3 list are sorted, 
then this function is log N time binary search, so you get n*log(n)^2.

case 2: If the lists are unordered, 
then each search will take n time (where n is the length of the each list)... and thus it will be n * n * n = n^3

Answer (score 0):

For the given algorithm:

foreach item (n) you're looping through 2 other arrays (2f(n)) .. so it's **n*2f(n) = o(n*f(n))**

BTW, best way to do it is:
Keep an array or hash of the items you find in the first array.
Then go through the other 2 arrays and see if they have items that are already found.

Saving items in array or hash, and Lookup is O(1).
And you're just looping through the 3 arrays one time each, so you have a complexity of **O(max{n,f(n)})**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the quick answer is O(n^3) assuming that they all have the same length. The worst case is that we find the element we are looking for in a2 at the last position, so we will span the whole array, and the same for a3 or it doesn't exist in a3. and this is the same for all the elements in a1, by that, we will have to span the 3 arrays all the time, assuming that each has length n, then total complexity is of order n^3

Comment: Again, worst case is `3*n`. He's only searching for one item.

Comment: @JimMischel we have 3 loops, first one spanning a1, second and third one are searching in a2 and a3 respectively, so we've 3 loops each one can go from 1 to n, so it's n^3 not 3*n. if n is found in a2 means that we will search for n in a2, this can take up to n comparisons

Comment: how these loops are not nested? the 2 if conditions are inside the foreach loop, the found "operator" is a function that searches the array for this element, so they are nested

Comment: Yes, the loops are nested. But there's only one level of nesting, so it'll be 2n^2, not n^3.

Answer (score 0):

So in the worst case you described, where `a1` and `a2` are equal, and `a3` doesn't contain any common numbers with the others, then for each `n` in `a1` you will search `a2` and `a3`.

So it looks like the time to run will be proportional to `2n^2`. That is, it would be the same as writing:

```
int jcnt, kcnt;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        ++jcnt;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        ++kcnt;
    }
}
int total = jcnt+kcnt;
```

You'll find that `total` will be equal to `2n^2`.

Assuming, of course, that the arrays are unordered. If `a2` and `a3` are ordered and you can do binary search, then it would be `2n(log n)`.